# Why doesn't typescript complain when I DON'T return a Promise in an async function

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

I have an `async` function which I intend to return an object of type `MyResponseType`. As I understand, an `async` function must return a `Promise`, so I created the following:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import MyModel from './models/MyModel'
import { MyResponseType } from "../common/types";

const myFunc = async (
  title: string,
  text?: string
): Promise<MyResponseType> => {
  const result = await MyModel.create({
    title,
    text,
  });
  return {
    message: 'Success',
    result
  };
};
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the right way to return from an `async` function, assuming I want the result in a `resolved` state when the caller calls `await myFunc({...})`?
2. Why doesn't typescript complain that the return type is `MyResponseType`, even though it is expecting `Promise<MyResponseType>`? Is there some implicit conversion going on?

Comment: Returned values from `async` functions are always wrapped in a Promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Is this the right way to return from an `async` function, assuming I want the result in a resolved state when the caller calls `await myFunc({...})`?

Yes. (But it's a *fulfilled* state, not [just] a *resolved* state. More about promise terminology [in my blog post](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/02/08/lets-talk-about-how-to-talk-about-promises/).)

> 2. Why doesn't typescript complain that the return type is `MyResponseType`, even though it is expecting `Promise<MyResponseType>`? Is there some implicit conversion going on?

Not *conversion*, but yes, something implicit. `async` functions are syntactic sugar for promise creation and consumption. They **always** return promises. The value you provide with `return ___` is the *fulfillment value* used to fulfill the implicit promise they create.

In your example, `myFunc` runs synchronously until after it calls `MyModel.create`; once it has the promise from `create`, it passes it to `await` and the function creates and returns its own promise. Later, asynchronously, when the promise from `create` is *settled*, one of two things happens:

- If the promise from `create` is *fulfilled*, the logic of `myFunc` continues and, in this case, fulfills the promise from `myFunc` with the object you provide to `return`.
- If the promise from `create` is *rejected*, your function's promise is rejected with the rejection reason the `create` promise provided.

*(That's* slightly *simplified, but the gory details aren't necessary here.)*